# Two questions on commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

So, in quantum mechanics we know that $[x,p] = i\hbar$, but how do we know that it is true no matter what coordinates you use? Also, is it true or not that $e^{xp/\hbar} e^{-px/\hbar} = e^{i}$?
Can we just take the exponential like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In classical Hamiltonian mechanics you can choose any $x$ and then the $p$ is fixed by $[x,p]_{\mathrm{P.B.}}=1$ (where $[\cdot,\cdot]_{\mathrm{P.B.}}$ is the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket)). This *defines* the meaning of canonically conjugated momentum and $p$ is always understood to be canonically conjugated to $x$. Then the axiom of quantum mechanics tells you to promote Poisson brackets to $i\hbar$ times commutators.
2. To compute exponentials such as the one you write you have to use the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula). In this case it happens to work as you write because $[xp,px]=0$. But in general you need to be careful.

---

**Exercise**

*Show* $[xp,px]=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but on the exercise, I do: $(xp)(px)\psi = xp^2 (x \psi) =( x^2 p^2 )\psi$, and $(px)(xp)\psi = p(x^2 p\psi ) = (x^2 p^2) \psi + (p x^2)(p\psi)$ and it doesn't really match... (I assumed that$ p^2 x = 0$, like in Cartesian coordinates.)

Comment: No, $p^2x$ is not zero (because $\partial_x x = 1 + x \partial_x$). Think of $p$ and $x$ as operators such that $xp-px=i\hbar$, that's all you need to know.

Comment: Ok, now I got. Thanks, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics, $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are operators, meaning they are mathematical transformations, not merely variables as in classical mechanics. So we can represent any operator in various bases of our choosing, depending on what we're trying to do.

> how do we know that it is true no matter what coordinates you use?

The operator is an abstract algebraic object, which is represented in different bases, but it's still the same object. This is exactly what you're doing when you represent the position vector $\vec{r}$ in cartesian basis or in spherical basis - it's two different representations of the same underlying object. So whether we choose to represent $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ in a particular basis does not change the fact that they are still operators that do not commute. I recommend you prove this to yourself: take $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ in the position basis, and then take them in the momentum basis, and prove that the commutation relation holds in either case. That's not a general proof, but a proof-of-principle. There's lots of theory behind this stuff, called algebraic [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory), and its [relation](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/representation-theory-quantum.pdf) with quantum theory has been [studied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics_and_representation_theory) for about 100 years now!

Another way to say it: an operator algebra is basis-independent, which gives us the freedom to choose the basis we wish to compute things in. When you choose the coordinate basis, it is true for $any$ coordinate system of the lab frame. Do not confuse the lab frame of the physical system with the Hilbert space in which we model the quantum states of the system.

> Also, is it true or not that $e^{xp} - e^{px}= e^{i\hbar}$ ?

I think it's not as simple as that. Again, I invite you to try to prove/disprove this for yourself: take the commutation relation, and take the exponential of each side individually and then do algebra and see if the two sides equal each other. You may find [this](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Book%3A_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fowler)/03%3A_Mostly_1-D_Quantum_Mechanics/3.09%3A_Appendix-_Some_Exponential_Operator_Algebra) article on exponential operator algebra helpful.

Comment: Ok, the first part makes sense, but the article you shared seems a bit wacky, like in the proof, where I just don't understand for example how exactly you differentiate $e^{Ax}$, because in one he puts the A on the left and the other one on the right.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} e^{Ax} = A e^{Ax} = e^{Ax}A$ because $A$ commutes with $e^{Ax}$, since the latter is defined by $e^{Ax} = \sum_n^\infty A^nx^n/n!$.

Comment: @MannyC Ok, that's clear to me now, but what happens between the second and third line?

Comment: I'm afraid that if we start discussing that article this comment section will get too cluttered. You are welcome to ask another question.